# Renaming applications name in KDE taskbar

Tags: kde, taskbar, konsole

I grouped my applications according to their name in my KDE taskbar. I d now like to be able to rename some of those and to keep them grouped together.
To be precise, I often switch from administrative tasks to coding tasks and When I go to my code desktop an dclick on the Konsole group, I dont know which konsole contains my vim or any other type of taks I dedicated a konsole to.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to make this happen with some desktop file trickery, but not having a ton of success. In the mean time, maybe just make a separate virtual desktop for your admin tasks, and maybe add the Pager widget to your panel/taskbar?

Comment: So you don't use Konsoles in-built tabs, which you can name, but instead use separate instances of Konsole, which you group and then can not recognise by name? Maybe you're holding it wrong ... why not use Konsoles own tabs and name them from the right-click menu (IIRC)? What do you get if you choose not to group?

Answer (score 0):

Since I put all of my Ask Ubuntu rep on the line for this bounty, I can no longer comment on the question itself *(sigh)*.

Anyway, there was a hidden agenda to my bounty, specifically [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/11d7aq8/task_manager_issues_w_grouping_by_program_name/).

I was just trying to figure out if there is a generalized way to sneak hints to KDE to alter the task manager's grouping behavior. Hence, the solution to my problem happens to intersect with OP's initial intention.

Anyway, if there isn't any such facility, *e.g.* via `.desktop` file properties (probably isn't), it seems like a useful feature to consider for KDE.